# how to write a for loop in expected result in xquery match

Tags: dynamic, xquery, soapui

I have a assertion in xquery match like this:

```
let $size := count(tokenize("${DataSource#SendResponses}",',')

<Result>
{
for $z in tokenize(//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/SENDRESPONSES[1], ',')[position() lt $size]
return contains("${DataSource#SendResponses}",$z) 
}
</Result>
```

And I don't know how to write Expected result for that. i write a script like below but it dosen't work:

```
<Result>
{
for $x in (1 to count(tokenize("${DataSource#SendResponses}",',')) )
return true
}
</Result>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what XQuery engine you are using, but some of the Syntax looks like non-standard XQuery. Perhaps you could shed some light on that?

For example in standard XQuery 1.0, the following:

```
tokenize("${DataSource#SendResponses}",',')
```

Would not return any more tokens than the string you gave it, i.e. the result would be ("${DataSource#SendResponses}")

This is why I guess you must be using some sort of non-standard syntax, where there is some sort of variable substitution going on. If you can explain that, perhaps we can better help you.

Comment: when i use that on the "XQuery Expression" it works but on the "Expected Result" not. I don't know how to handle the "Expected Result" that assertion be true with "XQuery Expression" that I have

Comment: What XQuery processor are you using?